# JQuery smooth Scroll error

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with my smooth scroll script, which worked on another site I did, but its throwing up errors on my new site. The code is exactly the same.

```html
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="div2" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test 2
    </div>
    <button id="click">Click me</button>
</html>
```

This is the error I'm getting in Chrome and Opera:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):31)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Comment: I copy/pasted this code exactly to a test.html file on my local machine and had zero errors and it did exactly what I would have expected. Also, the "Run code snippet" works exactly as expected as well.

Comment: I tried in chrome and it is working for me

Comment: What would cause this error is `offset` isn't returning the expected object which would be caused by the lookup of `#div1` returning zero elements. What causes that would have to be that `div1` was not found, whether because the code ran before the element existed or the element never existed. That could be because you forgot the `$.ready`, misspelled the id or did something like left off the `#` or used a class selector `.`. These are the likely scenarios that would cause this. However this is all speculation as it can't be reproduced and I assume was fixed when making the example.